# How to Monitor EKS Node group Status in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm currently trying to monitor the **EKS Node group status**, sometimes my node groups show **degraded** and I want a **CloudWatch** alert whenever the status is in a Degraded state, I checked CloudWatch Metrics there are no standard metrics, and even I'm unable to find the event in Cloud trail,

[image]

Is there any possibility's to creating the alarm using **AWS Cloud trail events, Event bridge, or CloudWatch**
Kindly help to find the solution for this

Answer (score 1):

I think you can combine **Lambda** & **CloudWatch** & **EventBridge** service here to implement your simple health-check status for a single or multiple node groups.

For your health check Lambda function:

1. We create a Lambda with Python3 (3.9 for example)
2. We describe the node group using **Boto3**
3. We put a custom metric to CloudWatch metrics so if the status is `Active`, we put `1` else `0`.

When we have the function ready, we prepare the every 1 minutes (up to you) setup.

1. We create an EventBridge (EB) rule with every 1 min triggers
2. The EB rule destination is the Lambda function

Once we have enough data points from CloudWatch metrics, we can create a CloudWatch alarm to help us notifying to E-mail or others.

References:

- https://stackify.com/custom-metrics-aws-lambda/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/eks.html#EKS.Client.describe_nodegroup
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html

Answer (score 0):

For CloudWatch, please take a looks at this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/deploy-container-insights-EKS.html

Comment: This will guide me how to use container insights , but there are no metrics available for my requirement , is there any other solution can be implemented  @Christoph Fischer

Comment: In a previous project, we used Prometheus+Grafana to get metrics from the EKS cluster.